# Elements are not adding in the String List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I've been trying to build a calculator in flutter. And this is the expression evaluator function I've written.

```
class Evaluate {
  int i;
  double val;
  List<String> tokens = new List<String>();
  List<String> ops = new List<String>();
  List<double> values = new List<double>();

  double evaluateExpression(String str) {
    tokens = str.split("");
    stderr.writeln("tokens = $tokens \n 2");

    for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      if (isDigit(tokens[i].codeUnitAt(0))) {
        val = 0;
        while (i < tokens.length && isDigit(tokens[i].codeUnitAt(0))) {
          val = (val * 10) + double.parse(tokens[i]);
          i++;
        }

        values.add(val);

        stderr.writeln("values = $values \n 3");
      } else if (!isDigit(tokens[i].codeUnitAt(0))) {
        while (
            ops.isNotEmpty && precedence(ops.last) >= precedence(tokens[i])) {
          double val2 = values.last;
          values.removeLast();

          double val1 = values.last;
          values.removeLast();

          String op = ops.last;
          ops.removeLast();

          values.add(applyOp(val1, val2, op));
        }

        ops.add(tokens[i]);
        stderr.writeln("ops = $ops \n 4");
      }
    }

    while (ops.isNotEmpty) {
      double val2 = values.last;
      values.removeLast();

      double val1 = values.last;
      values.removeLast();

      String op = ops.last;
      ops.removeLast();

      values.add(applyOp(val1, val2, op));
    }
    return values.last;
  }
}
```

Elements of String data types[such as '+','-','*','/'] are not adding in the ops List.
I tried to take some logs while evaluating 2+2.

```
13:33:47.050    stderr  1
13:33:47.059    stderr  tokens = [2, +, 2] 2
13:33:47.063    stderr  values = [2.0] 3
13:33:47.064    stderr  values = [2.0, 2.0] 3
13:33:47.064    stderr  end
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? This is my first question on stack overflow so please ask me any other essential details required.

Comment: The information is quite limited. Can you explain what is going wrong? The question is quite generic. What are the kind of elements that are not going into the list and since there are two `<String>` lists there, which in particular, or both are having issues?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the package expressions, I think it could provide aid to your need. You can evaluate any Expression String using this package

[Expressions Package](https://pub.dev/packages/expressions)

Comment: I can definitely use this package, but I want to write and learn on my own. So please help me in fixing the above code.